# Meaning of Equation of a line

Tags: analytic-geometry, plane-geometry, planar-graphs

What do we mean by "equation of a line"? How would it be defined? I know its form but what is it exactly?

Comment: It is an equation whose solutions are exactly the points on the line.

Comment: If you have a free parameter $x$ and a dependent variable $y$, and some equation that connects them (for example $y=x^2$ or $y=2x+1$), then you can plot the points that fulfill this condition on the $xy$-plane. Sometimes, it forms a straight line. In that case, the equation can be the "equation of that line".

Comment: Which equation ? Implicit, explicit, parametric ? 2D ? 3D ?

Answer (score 0):

To simplify the discussion, I will treat the “line” as a “straight line”. The logic is extendable to other “conic lines”.

A line is a collection of related points with co-ordinates (x, y) in the xy-plane.

The equation of a line is a way to relate the x and y.

For example, if a line goes through A(3, 4) and B(7, 8), we want to find out the relation (i.e. the common characteristics) between the x-coordinate and the y-coordinate of some other point P(x, y) lying on the same line. In this case, P is a representative of all the points on that line. A simple guess is y – x = 1 and it shows a relation between x and y.

Some characteristics are easy to guess from the given but most of them are not. That is why we need to develop different “forms” to help us to find such relation without going through wild guessing or the process by starting from square one.